# How to check the drop down option value is present or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am checking whether the RP value is present or not in DropDown option. My Code

```
var RP = @HttpContext.Current.Session["ResourcePlanId"];
  @isResourcePlanText = $("#NoteRP option[value='RP']").length > 0;
```

The problem is that Jquery is not taking the RP value at runtime. if I Put RP =35 then it is not recognized RP Value if I put `option[value= 35]")` it is giving me `length 1`. Please Suggest some way so I can put the Dynamic value in RP.